# Perl looping printing it's results multiple times

Tags: perl, loops

I want to compare a line with every other line in a file, if the first three columns are identical, I want to combine these lines and add their fourth columns together

This is my perl script so far

```
while (<>){
    my ($let, $start, $stop, $num) = split;
    if ( defined($oldLet) ){
        if ($let eq $oldLet and $start == $oldStart and $stop == $oldStop) {
            print $chr,"\t",$start,"\t",$stop,"\t",$num + $oldNum, "\n";
        }
    }
    my $oldLet = $let;
    my $oldStart = $start;
    my $oldStop = $stop;
    my $oldNum = $num;
}
```

This is what my input looks like

```
a   4360    5440    23
a   4360    5440    44
a   4360    5440    247
b   0   1090    10
b   0   1090    11
b   1090    3550    10
b   1090    3550    11
```

This is what I want as output

```
a   4360    5440    314
a   0   1090    21
a   1090    3550    21
```

Right now I am getting nothing

Comment: add `use strict` and `use warnings` in your script. and your `$chr` variable is not declared in your script can you please make it clear

Answer (score 2):

If you added `use warnings` and `use strict` to your code, you would see:

```
Global symbol "$oldLet" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$oldLet" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$oldStart" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$oldStop" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$chr" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$oldNum" requires explicit package name at foo.pl line 10.
Execution of foo.pl aborted due to compilation errors. at foo.pl line 18.
```

The problem is that you are using variables that have not been declared, so they are implicitly empty, so your `if ( defined $oldLet )` will not be true.

Solution is to declare your variables before the `while` loop.

Another issue is that you try to print `$chr` when you probably mean `$let`.

Here is a working version:

**count.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my ($oldLet,$oldStart,$oldStop,$oldNum);
while (<>) {
    my ($let, $start, $stop, $num) = split;
    if ( defined $oldLet ) {
        if ($let eq $oldLet and $start == $oldStart and $stop == $oldStop) {
            $oldNum += $num; # Add up the num column
        } else {
            # Output the results
            print $oldLet,"\t",$oldStart,"\t",$oldStop,"\t",$oldNum, "\n";
            $oldNum = $num;
        }
    } else {
        $oldNum = $num;
    }

    $oldLet = $let;
    $oldStart = $start;
    $oldStop = $stop;
}

# Last group
print $oldLet,"\t",$oldStart,"\t",$oldStop,"\t",$oldNum, "\n";
```

**Output**

```
cat input | perl count.pl

a       4360    5440    314
b       0       1090    21
b       1090    3550    21
```